How do I make reimbursements easier on my students?
In short, the reimbursement structure of academia sucks. I hated it as a grad student and I hate it now. I want my students to go to conferences but they struggle waiting for reimbursements as it can take months. Is there anything I can do to help them? I thought of just buying everything on my personal card then getting reimbursed from grants myself but this seems like an unsustainable solution, especially as the number of students grows. Is there any way of making this easier on my students?
Let me preempt some comments by saying I have talked to office people about this and they were not very helpful.

become better friends with the people in the office. Or, private loans to your grad students (also a possible bad idea). Pay your grad students enough they can wait 2-4 months to get paid back for travel?

Funding agencies have their rules, partly to prevent fraud. If you can't find a local solution, you are probably stuck. make sure the students know what is likely to occur.

@RichardErickson I wish my students got paid more but that is out of my hands.

Just to mention, you are quite lucky that people at your university get reimbursed for conferences. In other places, they don't (or at least, not for all expenses - only travel or only accomodation; only for conferences abroad, not same county).

Does the funding come from grants already received?

And, does reimbursement come from the university or an agency? Who signs the checks or whatever?

@bestmedstudentthatneverwas While I understand that's your experience, it's absolutely ridiculous and sometimes illegal for anyone to have to pay their own way for work travel.

@RichardErickson Attending a major conference can easily involve an intercontinental flight including a few shorter legs plus a conference fee upwards of 1000 €/$/£. Having to front the total of several thousand is going to noticeably cut into the reserves of even very well paid students/postdocs (at least by EU standards, perhaps it's different in the US). And both of those expenses typically have to be paid many months in advance, so they'll have to wait for half a year before it is repaid.

Maybe one could form a non-profit association that offers loans at low interest rates to students to go to academic conferences.

@TooTea,  I am aware meetings can cost thousands of dollars/Euros/Pounds. Sometimes mechanisms exist such as bonus scholarships or travel scholarships that professors can use to get extra funds to students. The University I attended also offered travel advances (and still appears to https://www.depts.ttu.edu/procurement/resources/training-and-work-aids/documents/travel-services/procurement-travel-tips.pdf).  The answer by yourfriendlyresearchadmin mentions many possible ideas.  Working with (rather than against) people like them can make your life much easier.

This is crazy to me. In the country I live in, this kind of thing is just illegal. It's required by law that you can get an advance in this kind of situation. You can't require the employee to use their own money to temporarily fund expenses in this way.

Unfortunately, as an academic you rarely have the power to make these sorts of changes, this is administration's remit and they typically don't like academics trying to circumvent their processes, even if said processes are rubbish and not fit for purpose. Best you can usually do is petition for change at your school/faculty meetings.

Do not pay and wait for getting it back from your students! What if the university denies the payment? Do you cover the cost? Do you ask the student to pay it back to you? Sounds like a bad idea once something unusual happens.

@AliceRyhl I guess in Germany you also cannot make employees pay for conferences from their own money in advance, but if you insist, the consequence would probably just be that they tell you not to go to conferences.

What country are you in? I have attended academic conferences as a PhD student enrolled in a Spanish university and as a post doc in a French one, and I have never ever had to pay out of pocket for anything other than the daily expenses I incurred while there (e.g. food). For those, I needed to keep the receipts and ask to be reimbursed, but nobody expected me to pay out of pocket for the hefty things like air fare or accommodation.

@terdon I am in the US and this is standard practice at every US university I know.

Wow. That's... just crazy! Please edit that into the question since it is very relevant. I only spent around 10-12 years in academia, as a PhD student and post doc (long post doc :P), so I don't claim to be an expert, but my limited experience, as well as common sense, suggests this is not standard in most places as this means that only the richest students would ever be able to travel.

@terdon I agree that this is crazy. I hate this system and it is deeply unfair to students who come from less well off backgrounds. Given the importance of travel to the career of students, changing the administration around this would be one very basic way to make math more accessible. In the mean time, I want to help my students not be too burdened by this stupid system.

In the absence of finding a way to make the whole process quicker, which seems like a tall order for anyone, could some of the expenses be charged to university accounts ahead of time to reduce the outstanding balances? Especially flights and registration fees are preferably paid months before a trip to get the lowest rates, but it's unreasonable to expect a student to front this money for many months. Where I am, such expenses can be charged to university credit cards at the time of payment if the travel will be paid for by the university (whether from grant money or otherwise). While I don't think students are typically eligible to have a card themselves, their flights and registration fees can be charged to cards held by departmental office staff (possibly also to cards held by faculty, but I haven't had reason to explore this). Of course, if the office people didn't mention this as an option, maybe it isn't available to you. Perhaps ask your faculty colleagues if they have developed some other strategy.

We have a setup like this where I work.  You can ask for a travel advance providing as collateral the appropriate travel and registration receipts paid ahead of time.  There is some probability that things go sideways and you have to cancel, and you have to fill out the reimbursement form twice, but on balance that's the way my students do it.

At least here (Germany) it’s possible for the university to directly pay some things (train and flight tickets, plus participation fees) and to get a general advance reimbursement based on estimated costs. It’s horrible paperwork, but that makes it suitable for supervisors to offer help their students with it.

@MisterMiyagi That should also be the correct way to handle Anyon's direct question (and what most larger companies do). There shouldn't be a need for much reimbursement for a business travel, because the organization is paying directly for virtually all of it. The core issue is that not all universities have actually gone that route yet (sometimes because of resistance of faculty, who want to continue getting personal benefits for business expenses).

I'm a PhD student (in the UK) and I'm required to book my travel through a specific provider the university uses. I provide a reference number for the grant or department it is being charged to and someone has to manually approve it. This means all the big upfront expenses never go anywhere near my personal card.

Research administrator here; I have been approving reimbursements for the last 15 years.  There are a few things to consider to make things easier.  This perspective is US-based.
The Rules
Reimbursement rules stem from IRS rules for reimbursement.  Many of the rules people dislike come from the IRS and not the institution.  E.g., the fact that a trip must be completed prior to being reimbursed is because you could book a refundable trip, get reimbursed, cancel the trip and make money off the reimbursement.  This is income, and the IRS would want that to be taxed.  Reimbursements are by definition non-taxable.  I always tell people, "you can't get something for nothing".
In addition to the IRS rules, there can be many additional layers of rules.  The most common layer relates to sponsored funding.  E.g., you may not be able to have a flight on a foreign air carrier for US federal funding.  There can be complicated rules for this requirement as well, which again stems from Federal law.  Some institutions require receipts for every charge; others do not.  There is some flexibility with certain rules, so institutions are required to make policies and enforce them consistently.
Advice

Some institutions have travel credit cards that allow for prepayment of expenses.  This process will vary by institution, but you should see what is allowed here.  At my institution, faculty cannot put lab member charges on their travel cards.  However, we have a separate department card that allows for us to do this.
Learn the rules on behalf of your lab and set up basic ways of doing business.  If you can work out the rules with an administrator, you can help set a lab norm.  E.g., if your institution allows receipts or per diem, pick one method and use it consistently for your lab.  Work with the administrator to find a "recipe" that they can follow every single time.  Often the problem is that there are too many choices.
Find out if your institution offers a travel agent service.  Not all do, but some pay for this specifically to ease the travel process for researchers.  The benefits include having someone who knows federal travel rules and someone who can help with rebooking in the event of a problem.  Some students want to have agency to book what they want, but this often leads to avoidable complications.  Travel agent receipts also meet the definition of receipt for institutions and are streamlined documentation. I see many folks providing confirmations and not receipts, and they don't realize that we need to see proof of payment.  Travel agent receipts have all the right information.
Avoid combining personal and business travel.  Many folks want to do this (and I totally get it), but it can delay reimbursement. When you do this, administrators have to separate out the personal travel.  This is time consuming, and often confusing.
There are apps that can help with collecting receipts.  They can also use the old-fashioned way of getting a document pouch and keeping all receipts in that pouch.  A surprising number of people provide unreadable receipts, missing receipts, and other non-compliant receipts.  This can lead to severe delays.
Overall, at the time of reimbursement, provide a very clear narrative about exactly what the trip consisted of, the reason for the trip (the business purpose), provide complete documentation, including a program from the conference with the person's name attached.

Reimbursements are really difficult because of all the rules attached and all the options available to travelers.  While it may not feel like the best choice, cutting down the options helps remove a lot of the burden.  Streamlined trips that require less explanation will always move faster.
That said, some administrators struggle with processing reimbursements, and if your administrator is not moving forward with a reimbursement within 30 days of receipts being provided, then you need to reach out to their supervisor to address the issue.  In my institution, there is a cut-off where after so many days the reimbursement becomes taxable to the traveler.
There have been many instances where administrators are the broken piece.  My colleagues are often overworked and backed up, but there are also some who just do not understand the complex work assigned to them.  Be gentle and thoughtful, but also make sure the system is working and do not wait too long to say something. So we recommend that travelers provide receipts within 30 days of the trip end, and the reimbursement should be paid out within 60 days to ensure all goes well.  It's very upsetting when we miss the deadline because no one was paying attention and ensuring it moved through the system.  We have the same problem with subawards -- they usually take so long to set up because administrators find them annoying, the work is distributed across multiple people, and there isn't one single person overseeing the whole process.  With a reimbursement, the traveler is the person who should be following up regularly to ensure they get their payment, but often, they do not realize it is their responsibility.

While using a travel agent does make a lot of the paperwork easier or shifts doing it to the travel agent it also tends to be considerably more expensive. Even if you get reimbursed, the money may still come out of a grant with a finite amount in it so people do care about that.

@quarague, this cost/benefit analysis will vary widely by institution.  My institution has 3 services, one costs $7 per booking, another is $30, and the third is $50.  We coach the PIs to go with the $7 or $30 option depending on the complexity of the travel.  At some point, good administration is worth paying for.  Some of our folks have complex or high-risk itineraries (e.g., doing fieldwork in an area known for hurricanes).  We need them to have support in the event that their flight is cancelled.  It's just an option to consider; for some it's great, others not so much.

@yourfriendlyresearchadmin Varies a lot. For awhile, my institution required use of a travel agency for booking airfare, which was always more expensive for us than purchasing the tickets directly would have been, and absolutely not any more convenient for anyone.

@BryanKrause, I appreciate what you're saying. However, I will say that I work at an institution that provides maximal freedom with travel, and the downside is folks travel as they want, and their choices often end up non-reimbursable--that's a really uncomfortable conversation, and it happens every day.  It's expensive to train hundreds of people on all the policies for all the funding, and many researchers do not prioritize the training that we offer. I can see why some institutions would go the way of requiring the use of a travel agency to lower risk. It's definitely tough to optimize for.

@quarague what’s “considerably more expensive”?  If you’re buying an airfare for $2k, what’s $50 of file fee for someone to do all the legwork of chasing airfares, possible connections etc?  Obviously not worth it if the airfare is $250, but at least for me the TA takes a burden away and provides support when things go sideways (which they often do these days).

@ZeroTheHero It depends a lot on how the travel agents works and how much they charge for their services. The example by yourfriendlyresearchadmin is on the cheap end. I had experiences more similar to Bryan Krause. They were mandatory to use and the surcharge was more in the range of $200. Additionally they where utterly incompetent and the only way to get a reasonable connection was to do all the research yourself and then tell them the specific connection you wanted. They would then book the connection you found for the price you found plus their fee. It varies, a lot.

@quarague yes I suppose that paying anything for incompetent service is too much…

Thank you for helpful information. I've always found working with administrative support people to be more helpful than working against/around them. Your posts always remind me of the helpful admis I've worked with past and present.

This is an outstanding answer and very much aligns with much of my experience as a faculty in a management position. It's easy to be upset about the silly things admins require us to do, but half the time those things come from legal requirements and the other half they come from the experience that, at scale, untrained faculty and students will sometimes do really problematic things.

Some universities (such as mine) are actually encouraging faculty and students to take annual leave before or after a conference trip as it looks good for environmental purposes, as it reduces the number of flights taken by their students or employees. Mine will even pay for the flights, as long any other expenses outside the conference dates are borne by the traveller. It's not terribly difficult to process the expenses as long as they are submitted in good faith.

I have a saying, "I mind bureaucracy less than I mind chaos."
When, at the end of my residency, I applied for hospital credentialing, the process was long and complicated, but the hospital provided me a well-designed packet that layed out all the steps I needed to take, in the order I needed to take them.  That was bureaucracy, but it wasn't aggravating because there was order to it. I just had to do the work of trudging through it.
On the other hand, where I work now, applying for something as straightforward as getting administrator privileges on my work laptop is chaotic. The rules are constantly changing, the rules aren't written down, different people give you different answers, and the web form is clearly designed from the perspective of the people approving or applying the privileges, not from the perspective of the person filling it out.  It has all sorts of cryptic fields that leave me scratching my head and asking "What does that mean?" or "How the hell would I know that?"
Since you are working for a university, the chance of actually simplifying or speeding the process is slim.  You are probably stuck with the bureaucracy. What you can do is try to reduce the chaos:

Document the process down to a tee. Make it as linear (step-by-step) and plain-spoken as possible. (Avoid nested links where the student needs to drill down into a sub-process, then come back up and re-orient themselves. That can give the instructions a maze-like feeling.) Include tips on common mistakes to avoid. If possible, explain the rationale behind some of the more esoteric steps so that they make sense and don't seem like some voodoo incantation. If there are forms to fill out, include examples that can be used as models to follow. Hopefully, the University process is a stable one and isn't constantly changing.  If it does change frequently, this will make it hard to maintain your documentation.  You may be able to find a well-documented process on a school website or policy. If so, point your students there so you don't have to maintain your parallel documentation.
Forewarn your students how long the process takes, or even how long individual steps will take.  This will at least allow students to plan ahead, to know what to expect, and to have a clue if something is taking longer than expected (indicating a possible problem). From my perspective, knowing when I can expect reimbursement, so I can plan for it, is more important than getting the payment quickly.


+1 for the last sentence. I remember as a student having a hefty reimbursement delayed, and it felt like someone saying "by the way, we've decided you're going to lend us a month's rent for an undetermined length of time". It can be difficult to manage that kind of thing when you don't have any savings to rely on, but it would have been much easier if I'd known in advance.

Don't make it easier, remove their necessity. Pay for large purchases (eg flights, accomodation, registration...) directly from your cost centre. Use your university-issued credit card. Get service providers to invoice you for payment through the university system directly from your grants.

That's unlikely to work at many universities, most academics do not have carte blanche to just use their grant money how they feel like it, the university still has to approve major purchases and it will be audited. It could even result in disciplinary action.

I'm just talking about payment, not approvals. You still need to go through all the appropriate channels to make sure you don't break other rules.

If you go through the appropriate channels, your payment will almost certainly be denied and you will be told to use the proper bureaucratic process.

Then I must have worked at a sane university.
